# How to run HTML 5 tags on IE 8 or older versions

Tags: html, dom

I was working on a project built on HTML 5 and got stuck with compatibility issues for Internet Explorer 8. Is there any way to run HTML 5 tags to work on IE 8 and older versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [html5shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to make html5 tags compatible with old version of IE

Answer (score 0):

Html5 new tags like **" form attibutes"** and all does't support in all the browers. chrome is good for html5